# Bootstrap, less, how to change number of @grid-columns for nested rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm building a bootstrap 3 layout and I'm trying to change the number of columns for the nested row so that the nested columns have the same width as top-level columns.
I tried something like this but to no avail.

```
<main id="container" class="section">
  <div class="main-body">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item-1">
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-2">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

.section{
    .container; 
}

.col-sm-2, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-8{
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
.main-body {
  .make-row();
  .sidebar {
    .make-sm-column(2);
  }
  .main-content {
    .make-sm-column(10);
  }
  @grid-columns: 10;
  .items {
    .make-row();
    .item-1{
      .make-sm-column(2);
    }
    .item-2{
      .make-sm-column(8);
    }
  }
  @grid-columns: 12;
}
```

The grid inside the nested row still seems to have 12 columns, and I want it to have 10.
I found the example above in this: [article](http://willschenk.com/bootstrap-advanced-grid-tricks/)
The guy did it in sass and I rewrote it in less because I'm not much of a sass user, but unfortunately it didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When converting a Sass code to Less the first most important thing to know is the difference in these languages [variable semantics](http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=2965).

Comment: So can you tell me what exactly am I doing wrong? This is supposed to be a simple example yet I can't figure it out. I only recently started using less and I never used sass before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Less variables are [lazy loaded](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading) (for more detailed/friendly tutorial on what this actually means for your code see [Variable Semantics](http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=2965)).

Thus the first problem of your snippet above is that `@grid-columns: 12;` at the end of the `.main-body` overrides `@grid-columns: 10;` (so that it simply has no effect there).

The second problem is more tricky, even if you remove `@grid-columns: 12;` at the end of the `.main-body`, `@grid-columns: 10;` still won't have any effect on the grid mixins as those will still use the value of the globally defined `@grid-columns` which is `12` (you could override the global value but that will apply to every grid class incl. defaults, i.e. not really our goal).

Well, to not bother you with more and more head-scratching details on variables scope, namespacing and visibility, here probably the most simple solution (among a few others):

Define `@grid-columns: 10;` inside `.items` (assuming this is the scope you need it) and then reimport the file that defines corresponding grid mixins also right inside `.items`, so that there you just get a copy of those grid mixins with `@grid-columns: 10;` applied:

```
.main-body {
    // here default `@grid-columns: 12` applies:
    .make-row();
    .sidebar      {.make-sm-column(2)}
    .main-content {.make-sm-column(10)}

    .items {
        // here we use 10 columns:
        @import (multiple) "<bootstrap>/less/mixins/grid.less";
        @grid-columns: 10;
        .make-row();
        .item-1 {.make-sm-column(2)}
        .item-2 {.make-sm-column(8)}
    }
}
```

Comment: Jesus christ, It works! I wanted to be able to do something like this since I first started using bootstrap. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

This should also work:

```
.section {
    .container;
}

.main-body {
    .make-row();

    .sidebar,
    .item-2 {
        .make-sm-column(2);
    }

    .item-1 {
        .make-sm-column(8);
    }
}
```

Edit: But it might be better to use Bootstraps classes in your html markup to prevent bloating your CSS file:

```
<main id="container" class="section">
  <div class="main-body row">
    <div class="sidebar col-sm-2">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item-1 col-sm-8">
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-2 col-sm-2">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Well, your code shows how to create default `2 of 12` and `8 of 12` column classes. But the question is about a separate 10-column grid (i.e. creating `2 of 10` and `8 of 10` column classes).

Comment: Not exactly, the code shows a `8 of 12` and  a `2 of 12` within a wrapper, and then another `2 of 12`, where the two `2 of 12`s are equally width. I think that's what the question and the linked article was about?

Comment: Yes but temporary changing the frameworks grid columns is not a nice solution. The end goal, nested columns but equally width, as described in the question and article, can be reached much easier with this approach.

Comment: I can't see any "nested columns but equally width" in the question. Instead it clearly states of "The grid inside the nested row still seems to have 12 columns, and I want it to have 10."

Comment: The next sentence links the [article](http://willschenk.com/bootstrap-advanced-grid-tricks/)

Comment: Well, let's try it from scracth: Yes, sure the same visual result is possible by doing different HTML layout, but in that context I guess you'd better stress that explicitly in your A, e.g. "*instead* of creating a separate nested grid with different number of columns (yet again, this is what the Q asks for), you *can* achieve the same result by applying proper column widths to the nested columns *without* creating a nested row at all". Otherwise it's absolutely not clear how your A answers "I'm building a bootstrap 3 layout and I'm trying to change the number of columns for the nested row".

Comment: Ok... btw the html layout isn't even different, just the css classes.