# Less variable becomes overwritten by the next file

Tags: css, less

I have the following structure:

```
app.less
      @import a.less
      @import b.less
```

a.less looks like:

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap/variables";
@grid-columns: 10;

.someClass{    
   .make-sm-column(5);
}
```

When I compile a.less to a.css I get:

```
.aClass{
  ...
  width: 50%;
}
```

b.less looks like:

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap/variables";
@grid-columns: 100;
```

So when app.less is compiled to app.css I get

```
.aClass{
  ...
  width: 5%;
}
```

It seems like @grid-columns becomes overwritten by b.less. How can I prevent this behavior?

UPDATE: Even if I put @grid-columns: 10 inside a class it still not working. It seems like a variable is not scope to a selector.

Comment: change the names?

Comment: Dont use same variable names

Comment: Probably what you need is something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414276. "It seems like a variable is not scope to a selector." - it is actually but since `.make-sm-column` is a global mixing it's supposed to look for global `@grid-columns` first (hence the class scoped variable has no effect) - see the link to find how to trick it.

Answer (score 1):

> When defining a variable twice, the last definition of the variable is used, searching from the current scope upwards. This is similar to css itself where the last property inside a definition is used to determine the value.
>   http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature

Same scope in both, same variable name, only the second will be used. Try using different variable names:

```
@grid-columns-100: 100;
@grid-columns-10: 10;
```

Comment: So how in this case I can use a mixin (for example, make-xs-column of a bootstrap.less) where this variable grid-columns is used? How can I use this mixin in different files using different values of grid-columns variable?

Comment: You can pass parameters to mixins, at least in SASS (I haven't used Less much).

Comment: Yes, I can, but I was curious how can I use a provided by bootstrap mixin. It's mentioned in the article http://willschenk.com/bootstrap-advanced-grid-tricks/ that a variable grid-columns is scoped to a selector but it seems like it's not working like that.